# Checkbox not staying active after switching tabs MUI React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a todolist, and i want to keep a checkbox active until i click it again. however, when i switch tabs from 'complete' to 'incomplete' then back to 'complete', the checkbox dissapears. how would i modify the state to keep the checkboxes active even when switching tabs? I'm using MUI v5.

```
function Todo({
 text,
 todo,
 todos,
 setTodos,
 checked,
 setChecked,
 labelId,
 value,
}) {
 const deleteHandler = () => {
   setTodos(todos.filter((el) => el.id !== todo.id));
 };

 const completeHandler = () => {
   setTodos(
     todos.map((item) => {
       if (item.id === todo.id) {
         return {
           ...item,
           completed: !item.completed,
         };
       }
       return item;
     })
   );
 };

 return (
   <ListItem
     key={value}
     secondaryAction={
       <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete" onClick={deleteHandler}>
         <DeleteIcon />
       </IconButton>
     }
     disablePadding
   >
     <ListItemButton onClick={completeHandler} dense>
       <ListItemIcon>
         <Checkbox disableRipple />
       </ListItemIcon>
       <ListItemText primary={text} />
     </ListItemButton>
   </ListItem>
 );
}

export default Todo;
```

Comment: You have to use a state management library, such as Redux or Flux

Comment: Or use `React Context`, and you can also use the `local storage`

Comment: Check out this link to understand more https://blog.bitsrc.io/5-methods-to-persisting-state-between-page-reloads-in-react-8fc9abd3fa2f